# play youtube video in full screen mode in my android app

Tags: android, youtube

I am using the following code to play youtube videos in my app.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                         Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid")));
```

I would like the youtube videos to open in full screen mode. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

Comment: thanks.. but I don't think your link covers playing of videos in full screen. In my app, videos are getting played, but the youtube videos are not fullscreen and I have to do that manually as of now.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer for this question. I think gdata apis could be of some help.

Comment: Try using open youtube player. This has helped me. This is the link for it: http://keyeslabs.com/joomla/projects/youtube-player/244-open-youtube-activity-project-launched-by-keyes-labs

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I failed at this initially, I eventually succeeded by following the instructions at this linkc
http://keyeslabs.com/joomla/projects/youtube-player/244-open-youtube-activity-project-launched-by-keyes-labs

Here you create your own video player and the video gets played in it

Comment: This is a link only answer. Consider copying relevant information here.

Answer (score 12):

Found this solution today:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID"));
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + video_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

The reason is the different Uri. The one you are currently using is just supplying content via http: that happens to be video and get's resolved to youtube. The one with "vnd.youtube" is actually telling the system that you have video content you would like one of the native apps to take care of.

Ahh, if you want to actually play full screen video without using the youtube app (which you can not control) you don't you try to just make your own VideoView?
Check out this link
[playback video full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574654/playback-video-full-screen)

Comment: Did you try just creating you own VideoView?

Comment: I tried videoview earlier. But then, there was a problem with the videos not being played. Then I tried out the option in my code mentioned above. The videos are being played, but now I am stuck with this full screen issue..

Comment: So your going to have to fix your VideoView playback problem because I don't think your gonna be able to get control of YouTube to make is start in full screen

Comment: I tried using video view. But again, that did not work..I used this link here this time. 
http://www.keyeslabs.com/joomla/samplecode/introvideoactivity/IntroVideoActivity.java

Not sure how this is gonna work.. It would be great if anyone can show me their working code for a videoview streaming youtube videos.

Comment: yeah couldn't get it working either.  It doesn't allow you to force full screen view