# how to play YouTube video with fullscreen in android application

Tags: android

I want to play the YouTube video in fullscreen mode by default in my Android application. I have tried with the options `force_full screen` and `flag_full screen`, but nothing is working.Can you please help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: To play the video, do you want to open the Youtube app, or play it within your app through Youtube SDK?

Comment: I want to play youtube video within my app.

Answer (score 3):

This should be work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com  /watch?v=VIDEOID"));
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks [DagW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108441/play-youtube-video-in-full-screen-mode-in-my-android-app)

Comment: Yes DagW. I have used the above code.but it didnot work.

Comment: There is no error. Video doesn't play in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, if you use YouTube SDK

```
player.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlaying() {
                        player.setFullscreen(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPaused() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopped() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSeekTo(int i) {

                    }
                });
```