# Youtube API - How to force full screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a question in the Youtube API.
I use the 'player.cueVideos' command to run the videos, but I wish that when a person hit the watch button they would be forced to full screen.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [play youtube video in full screen mode in my android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108441/play-youtube-video-in-full-screen-mode-in-my-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue with forcing a iframe YouTube embed video full-screen on an Android. From the information that I've found it is impossible to force fullscreen on play on the Android with the YouTube API.

From a [Codepen.io example by bfred-it](https://codepen.io/bfred-it/pen/GgOvLM):

> Mobile browsers
>
> This is the default behavior on iPhone, but it cannot work anywhere else (Android, iPad) since
>
> - to `play()` a video or to `requestFullScreen()` you need a user tap **in the same document** (read: not across the iframe)
>
> This means that
>
> - you can't call `requestFullScreen()` when the video emits the event `onplay`
> - you can't trigger `play()` via YouTube API (it would cross the frame) **and** call `requestFullScreen()` in the same tap
>
> So with one tap **either** you play the video **or** get it fullscreen; you'll always need two separate taps if you use YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements 
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, 
        YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

    private YouTubePlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_activity);

        YouTubePlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        playerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, 
            YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        //use this to hide controls
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        player = youTubePlayer;
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(this);
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        player.setFullscreen(true);
    }
}
```

Also, implement other methods that come with the interfaces.

`YOUTUBE_API_KEY` get your api key in [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

`VIDEO_ID` You need to use the video's ID not full URL.

Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary).