# How to play video in full screen in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [playback video full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574654/playback-video-full-screen)

I am new to Android application development. I developed an application, in which I play a video file. It is working properly, but the video is not enabled to be played in full screen as required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764/hiding-title-in-a-fullscreen-mode try this link

Comment: Refer the below link

[playback video full screen][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574654/playback-video-full-screen

Answer (score 10):

Just use the following xml for your video view and it should play in fullscreen mode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

See this thread for more:
[playback video full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574654/playback-video-full-screen?rq=1)