# Video plays on part of the screen after screen unlocked

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-orientation

I am using **VideoView** for playing video with given URL. I want video full screen. Everything is working well. But am facing strange problem. **When you turn off screen and then unlock it, video plays on part of the screen**.. approximately 3/4th area of the screen.. I searched a lot but still unable to find solution.

Just FYI, my whole application works only in portrait mode and only video plays in only landscape mode. Don't know whether this is the cause or not. But this should not be.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: may this be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574654/playback-video-full-screen

Comment: After unlock the onResume is called for your activity so that all of the surfaces used by your MediaPlayer or VideoView will be reconstructed , you should handle both onResume and onPause