# Android-fullscreen seamless video loop in background

Tags: android, video, android-fullscreen

I am created an Android app thta needs to have a fullscreen seemless video loop playing in the background. By 'in the background' I mean that there will be buttons on top of the video.

I've read these threadw already
[playback video full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574654/playback-video-full-screen)
[Integrating video file in android app as app background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830111/integrating-video-file-in-android-app-as-app-background)

but I'm still confused about the following

1 Is the mediaplayer needed for video playback?

2 Will using OnCompletionListener create a 'seamless' loop or will there be a 'hiccup' as the video loops?

Comment: I just tested an app with no MediaPlayer. It works fine. OnCompletionListener will work. Could you use a Timer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the setOnPreparedListener to tell the MediaPlayer to loop and start

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();

            }
        });
```

This is seemless on some devices, but can cause a frame or two of stutter on others :/