# Play a video on Android full screen from website link

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview, android-video-player

I have a website which lists the links to videos. Clicking on these links will play video on browser.
Now, I am planning to develop an Android app for my website. The way I am going to do is just framing this website inside Android app.
Now, when I click on these links inside the Android app, the video is getting played as like it plays on the browser. But I need it in a way such that when a user clicks on these links the video should play automatically on full screen landscape mode.

What modification should be done in the coding to play this video on full screen upon clicking on the video link?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4943667/6630837)